# NoSuchMethodException for straight-forward ViewModel in Jetpack Compose setup

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, jetpack

The setup below seems straight-forward (to me) but fails with `FATAL EXCEPTION: main` due to `java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.mydummy.viewmodeltesting.DummyViewModel.<init> []`.

That's interesting. The `init()` method is there. I also tested this with a completely new `EmptyActivity` project in Android Studio, which has the following setup.

*MainActivity.kt*

```kotlin
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    val viewModel: DummyViewModel by viewModels()
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            ViewModelTestingTheme {
                val data by viewModel.dataState.collectAsState()
                Surface(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(), color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background) {
                    ShowDataList(dataList = data)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun ShowDataList(dataList: List<DummyMetadata>, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        LazyColumn(modifier = Modifier) {
            items(dataList) { data -> ShowDataItem(model = data)}
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun ShowDataItem(model: DummyMetadata) {
    Card(shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp), modifier = Modifier) {
        Text(text = model.title)
    }
}
```

*DummyViewModel.kt*

```kotlin
class DummyViewModel(private val _repository: DummyRepository): ViewModel() {
    private val _dataState = MutableStateFlow<List<DummyMetadata>>(emptyList())
    val dataState: StateFlow<List<DummyMetadata>> = _dataState

    init {
        fetchData()
    }

    private fun fetchData() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            try {
                val data = _repository.collectDummyData()
                _dataState.value = data
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                // TODO Error handling or at least better logging
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

*DummyRepository.kt*

```kotlin
class DummyRepository {
    suspend fun collectDummyData(): List<DummyMetadata> {
        return listOf(
            DummyMetadata("First dummy"),
            DummyMetadata("Second dummy"),
            DummyMetadata("Last dummy")
        )
    }
}
```

And the data class in *DummyMetadata.kt* is:

```kotlin
data class DummyMetadata(
    val title: String
)
```

That's all. The ViewModel class and the associated Repository & data model look fine. Don't they?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.mydummy.viewmodeltesting.DummyViewModel.<init> [].`
It means that there isn't a no-argument constructor available. `by viewModels()` seems not to be able to create this view model instance without a custom factory

Comment: You could also use something like a dependency injection library (for example: [hilt](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android)), or just manually create the view model instance by passing in a manually created instance of the repository